# Control an Arduino Uno with a PHP script

Tags: arduino

Is it possible to control an Arduino Uno with a PHP webpage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can connect your Arduino via USB to your server, and use [phpSerial](http://code.google.com/p/php-serial/).

Or you can connect to your Arduino with an Ethernet shield. In [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) you can [open a stream](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php) to your Arduino.

You can write your own protocol to communicate, for example:

To read the value of an analog input:

1. PHP: sends `rA0` followed by ('\n').
2. Arduino parses `rA0`: and sends the value of analog input A0 back in [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) followed by a newline ('\n').

A little more explanation:

1. PHP wants to read an analog value or an [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output) state so the first char is `r` (to set an I/O port or [PWM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) a `w`)
2. To specify if it is an analog or a digital I/O port, an 'A' or a 'D'
3. To specify the port: the ASCII number of the port 0.
4. To know where the command ends; send a newline.

On the Arduino side;

1. Parse the incoming command.
2. If the first char is not equal to 'r' or 'w' then it's not a read or write command; so the command is invalid.
3. If the second char is not equal to 'A' or 'D' then it's not an analog or a digital value, the command is invalid.
4. Then for the number, if it can be more than one char, make a char array of three chars, and fill these until you receive a '\n', or more than three ASCII numbers. With `atoi()` you can parse ASCII to integers.

If it is a legal command; respond to the command.